# How to check if filename contains substring in C#

Tags: c#, .net

I have a folder with files named

1. myfileone
2. myfiletwo
3. myfilethree

How can I check if  file "myfilethree" is present.

I mean is there another method other than `IsFileExist()` method, i.e like filename contains substring "three"?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Substring:

```
bool contains  = Directory.EnumerateFiles(path).Any(f => f.Contains("three"));
```

Case-insensitive substring:

```
bool contains  = Directory.EnumerateFiles(path).Any(f => f.IndexOf("three", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) > 0);
```

Case-insensitive comparison:

```
bool contains  = Directory.EnumerateFiles(path).Any(f => String.Equals(f, "myfilethree", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
```

Get file names matching a wildcard criteria:

```
IEnumerable<string> files = Directory.EnumerateFiles(path, "three*.*"); // lazy file system lookup

string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(path, "three*.*"); // not lazy
```

Comment: Great answer, though how would I do this with 2 lists? I have a List<string> that I'd like to compare against.

Comment: @Robula: Please elaborate your question. Or ask another question and leave a link here.

Comment: Sorry, I found what I needed. `(from file in files from guid in guidsToDeleteList where file.Contains(guid) select file)`

Answer (score 5):

If I understand your question correctly, you could do something like

`Directory.GetFiles(directoryPath, "*three*")`

or

`Directory.GetFiles(directoryPath).Where(f => f.Contains("three"))`

Both of these will give you all the names of all files with `three` in it.

Answer (score 1):

I am not that familiar with IO but maybe this would work ? Requires `using System.Linq`

```
System.IO.Directory.GetFiles("PATH").Where(s => s.Contains("three"));
```

EDIT: Note that this returns array of strings.