# SSIS how to read today's file with wildcard

Tags: sql-server, ssis

In our folder, we have file names in this format myFile_yyyyMMddHHmmss.txt, for ex: 20230920095749.txt, 20230919051704.txt.

If today is 09/20/2023, in SSIS package, I only want to read today's file, ie 20230920095749.txt in the above example.

Then, I want to populate SQL Server table with this file information.

How can I do this in SSIS package ?

To read file with date stamp, I use this method:

1. In the Script Task, set a user variable "DateVar" to

   Dts.Variables["User::DateVar"].Value = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd");
2. In the Connection Managers for the Flat File, I set Expressions to

   @[User::InputFilePath] +  @[User::myFile] +  "_" + @[User::DateVar] + ".txt"

But how in SSIS can I read file that has both dynamic date stamp and the time stamp as myFile_yyyyMMddHHmmss.txt, then populate SQL Server table with the file data ?
Thank you

Comment: Instead of using a file connection, you can read the files in your script task. You can loop over the files in the directory and use Contains() to determine if a particular filename contains the date string you want. If it does, then read the file contents using a [File Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.appendalllines?view=net-7.0) such as [ReadAllText()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.readalltext?view=net-7.0)

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7470689/how-to-check-if-filename-contains-substring-in-c-sharp) is an example of finding files that contain a string in the filename. And [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7980456/reading-from-a-text-file-in-c-sharp) is an example of how to read the file contents.

Comment: If I read the file contents in script, then I would have to populate the sql server database in the script also, which I am trying not to do.

Comment: Then perhaps [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11634322/ssis-flat-file-wildcard-filename) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69215306/how-do-i-use-a-wild-card-with-alphabets-of-file-name-in-ssis-foreach-loop-contai) would be an option? So basically, add a `*` wildcard after the date var in the expression where you're building the file name. Something like this: `@[User::InputFilePath] + @[User::myFile] + "_" + @[User::DateVar] + "*.txt"`

Comment: When using @[User::InputFilePath] + @[User::myFile] + "_" + @[User::DateVar] + "*.txt", I got this error: [Flat File Source [2]] Error: Cannot open the datafile "\\myServer\Files\myFile_20230920*.txt". even though the file exists

Comment: You're missing the `*`. Did you try `...+ "*.txt"`

Comment: Also, that error suggests that there is a permissions issue, not that the file isn't found.  Try googling for that error.

Comment: Sorry, a typo, it says [Flat File Source [2]] Error: Cannot open the datafile "\\myServer\Files\myFile_20230920*.txt". And it's not a permission issue, because if the file name is myFile_20230920.txt (without the time stamp), it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would go about this a different route.

I'll define 4 variables, all of type String

[image]

- CurrentDate - builds out the YYYYMMDD string and the expression I use is

  (DT_WSTR, 4)DATEPART("YEAR",@[System::StartTime])

  - RIGHT("0" + (DT_WSTR, 2)DATEPART("MONTH",@[System::StartTime]),2)
  - RIGHT("0" + (DT_WSTR, 2)DATEPART("DAY",@[System::StartTime]),2)
- CurrentFile - this will receive the fully qualified path to the file
- FileMask - this will be define the mask or shape of the file we're looking for. We'll combine the static element "myFile_" and CurrentDate plus the wildcard `*`  That expression is

  "myFile_" +  @[User::CurrentDate] + "*.txt"

FolderInput - this is a static path to where we should start searching. I have mine initialized to "C:\ssisdata\Input\so_63605861" but a UNC/network path will serve just as well.

### Foreach File Enumerator

Add a ForEach Enumerator to your package. I don't care that you only need to find 1 file, this saves you from writing the code and more importantly, saves you from maintaining it.

I have mine configured like

[image]

You can see we change the enumerator to `Foreach File Enumerator`
We add in Expressions for `Directory` to map to `@[User::FolderInput]`
and `FileSpec` to map to `@[User::FileMask]`

Finally, in the Variable Mapping tab, we will assign the index of 0 to our variable @[User::CurrentFile]

[image]

### Testing

From a command prompt, I made a folder with your sample files in it

```
C:\>cd \ssisdata\Input
C:\ssisdata\Input>mkdir so_77144602
C:\ssisdata\Input>cd so_63605861
C:\ssisdata\Input\so_63605861>echo > myFile_20230919051704.txt
C:\ssisdata\Input\so_63605861>echo > myFile_20230920095749.txt
```

Success

[image]

### Flat File Connection Manager Expression

In response to a comment, the final piece is to wire up the relationship between the current value of @[User::CurrentFile] to the Flat File Connection Manager.

Right click and select Properties or select the connection manager and hit F4 to bring up the Properties window. Find Expressions, click the ellipses `...` and add a new one. The property is `ConnectionString` the value or expression is `@[User::CurrentFile]`

Comment: Thank you so much ! That did the trick ! Thank you thank you !

Comment: I'm missing something, how is the flat file connection manager setup? Should it be set to the current file variable?

Comment: @RateControl Correct in your Flat File Connection Manager, right click or hit F4 to bring up the Properties window. Find Expressions, click the ellipses `...` and add a new one. The property is `ConnectionString` the value or expression is `@[User::CurrentFile]`